# Analyzing jar files with sonar

Tags: sonarqube

I am using Sonarqube tool for analyzing jar files.My jar files only contains classes file and not source code. I want to know that if it is possible to scan jar files that only contains classes through Sonarqube.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is no.

The purpose of SonarQube is solely to analyse **source** code. All main features rely on the availability of the source - because in the end you end up on files to track issues or see the test coverage (for instance).